# Execute SQL conditionally based on database Compatibility Level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**The Problem**

I have a script that I need to execute on both SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019. If executing on Server 2019+, I want to use syntax that is only supported on that version (specifically, [Data Classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-sensitivity-classification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

What I want is something like this, where we simply skip Data Classification if running on a version before 2019:

```sql
DECLARE @compatibility_level TINYINT = 0;
SELECT @compatibility_level = compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase';
PRINT CONCAT('Database compatibility level is: ', @compatibility_level);

IF @compatibility_level >= 150
BEGIN
    ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO
        MyTable.Forename,
        MyTable.Surname
        WITH (LABEL='Confidential - GDPR', INFORMATION_TYPE='Name', RANK=MEDIUM);

    -- More classifications would be here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Data Classification will not be performed, as the compatibility level is not high enough';
END
```

If I run this on SQL Server 2019+, it works as expected. But if I run it on older version, it fails with `Incorrect syntax near 'SENSITIVITY'`, because it's parsing the whole script before executing it.

**Restrictions**

I should add that this is part of a set of database migration scripts that are being executed automatically, so I can't simply execute different scripts for different versions (not without a lot of work).

**Potential Solutions**

One solution I thought of is to build the SQL dynamically, inside the `IF` block. Something like:

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
@sql += 'ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO MyTable1.Column1 ... ;';
@sql += 'ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO MyTable2.Column1 ... ;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I haven't tried this, but presume it would work. It feels pretty ugly though - are there any other ways to achieve this in a single script?

Answer (score 1):

**Final Solution**

I went for the dynamic SQL solution, as it "just works", and it's the most obvious:

```sql
DECLARE @compatibility_level TINYINT = 0;
SELECT @compatibility_level = compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase';
PRINT CONCAT('Database compatibility level is: ', @compatibility_level);

-- Data Classification is only supported from SQL Server 2019 onwards, so we skip it if not supported
IF @compatibility_level >= 150
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    SELECT @sql += 'ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO 
        MySchema.MyTable1.Column1, 
        MySchema.MyTable1.Column2
        WITH (LABEL=''Confidential - GDPR'', INFORMATION_TYPE=''Name'', RANK=MEDIUM);' + CHAR(10);

    SELECT @sql += 'ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO 
        MySchema.MyTable2.Column1
        WITH (LABEL=''Confidential'', INFORMATION_TYPE=''Contact Info'', RANK=MEDIUM);' + CHAR(10);
        PRINT @sql;

    -- ...more classifications here, elided

    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Data Classification will not be performed, as database compatibility level %d is not high enough', 10, 1, @compatibility_level);
END;
```

**Other Potential Solutions**

1. I thought to use `NOEXEC`, to prevent executing SQL if the database compatibility level was too low:

```sql
DECLARE @compatibility_level TINYINT = 0;
SELECT @compatibility_level = compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase';
PRINT CONCAT('Database compatibility level is: ', @compatibility_level);

IF @compatibility_level < 150
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Data Classification will not be performed, as database compatibility level %d is not high enough', 10, 1, @compatibility_level);
      SET NOEXEC ON;
END;
GO

-- This will only be executed if database compatibility is >= 150
ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO
    MyTable.Forename,
    MyTable.Surname
    WITH (LABEL='Confidential - GDPR', INFORMATION_TYPE='Name', RANK=MEDIUM);

SET NOEXEC OFF;
GO
```

However, even with `NOEXEC` enabled, it still actually *interprets* the SQL - so this doesn't work if the *server* compatiblity level is too low (beforew SQL2019), regardless of the *database* compatiblity level.

2. @martin-cairney came up with another solution, using the `sp_addextendedproperty` function, and you can find an example [here](https://github.com/way0utwest/CreditSuisse/blob/b0af08e97a38bdc30e4099b2160ed2e9edc04631/Tables/dbo.Contacts.sql). I personally find having to mess around with "magic string" GUIDs for `sys_sensitivity_label_id` to be a PITA.
3. A further option would be to write directly to the `sys.extended_properties` table (this is exactly what `sp_addextendedproperty` does) - obviously this method isn't recommended.

Comment: You might also consider checking for the associated system objects to avoid needing to hard code any version-related checks. I [implement this exact approach](https://github.com/LowlyDBA/dba-multitool/blob/master/sp_doc.sql#L169) in a project, for example. It is a more future-proof approach (in the past MS has backported features to older versions, for example).